# Where does delegates' constructors and member functions are defined?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, reflector

When I was looking at the `Action` delegates in Reflector, I saw it has a constructor like

```
public Action(object @object, IntPtr method);
```

But I could not find any body for the same along with other member functions like `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` etc. I can only see the definitions for it. Where does these functions are defined? Are they defined outside of the .net BCLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates are handled specially by the CLR, basically. The compiler provides the signatures, but the CLR knows what to do with them.

Section 8.9.3 of [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) partition I talks about this:

> Delegates are the object-oriented equivalent of function pointers. Unlike function pointers, delegates are
>   object-oriented, type-safe, and secure. Delegates are created by defining a class that derives from the base type
>   System.Delegate (see Partition IV). Each delegate type shall provide a method named Invoke with appropriate
>   parameters, and each instance of a delegate forwards calls to its Invoke method to one or more compatible
>   static or instance methods on particular objects. The objects and methods to which it delegates are chosen when
>   the delegate instance is created.
>
> In addition to an instance constructor and an Invoke method, delegates can optionally have two additional
>   methods: BeginInvoke and EndInvoke. These are used for asynchronous calls.
>
> While, for the most part, delegates appear to be simply another kind of user-defined class, they are tightly
>   controlled. The implementations of the methods are provided by the VES, not user code. The only additional
>   members that can be defined on delegate types are static or instance methods.

(VES is the Virtual Execution System; the CLR is Microsoft's implementation of the VES.)

Comment: Jon Skeet to the rescue! Thanks man for this valuable information.