# Why delegate can be instantiated using constructor that take only one parameter?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am learning delegate in C#.

When Reading [this Microsoft C# Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176(v=vs.110).aspx), noticed the following code.

```
// Declare a delegate. 
delegate void Del(string str);

// Declare a method with the same signature as the delegate. 
static void Notify(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification received for: {0}", name);
}

// Create an instance of the delegate.
Del del1 = new Del(Notify);    //why delegate can be initialized by this way.
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779078/4910876)

> The delegate keyword is for the compiler to do some magic for you.
>   When you declare a new delegate with a custom signature,
>
> the compiler creates a new Type for you derived from MulticastDelegate
>   (which in turn derives from Delegate).

So Del is of type that derived from MuticastDelegate. But both MulticastDelegate and Delegate do not have constructor that take only one parameter. 
How how does this code works?

```
Del del1 = new Del(Notify);
```

Does compiler have done something with this?

Comment: @peter-duniho how does my question be a duplicate of this question, [Where does delegates' constructors and member functions are defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862152/where-does-delegates-constructors-and-member-functions-are-defined)?

Comment: As the answer on the marked duplicate explains, they aren't defined anywhere. The CLR handles them as a special case.

Comment: I know little about CLR, if possible, can you explain how CLR handle in detail and simply in situation of my question?

Comment: "CLR" is "Common Language Runtime". Essentially, this is the host of your C# program, the code that executes your C# program at runtime. It is not possible to explain it both "in detail" and "simply". As explained elsewhere, delegate types are special, created on your behalf by the compiler, and constructed and invoked using logic available _only_ to delegate types, implemented by the CLR specifically for delegate types. The compiler provides members of the delegate type that _look_ like regular class member, but they aren't really. It's just mapping the C# syntax you're used to.